# Mapping schema using morphism lib in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json

I have following code where transform objects from one shape to another by defining a mapping schema using morphism lib:

```
import morphism from 'morphism';
    
const people = {
  'splits': [
    {
      'startDate': '2023-01-26',
      'endDate': '2024-12-31',
      'peopleId': 'emp_id_dummy',
      'addresses': [
        {
          'addressType': 'dummyType',
          'city': 'dummyCity',
          'country': 'dummyCountry',
        },
      ],
      'emailIds': [
        {
          'networkId': 'dummy66',
        },
        {
          'emailType': 'dummyType',
          'networkId': 'dummy77',
        },
      ],
      'names': [
        {
          'nameType': 'dummyType',
          'salutation': 'Mr.',
          'firstName': 'Fname',
          'lastName': 'Lname',
        },
      ],
      'birthInfo': [
        {
          'validFrom': '2023-01-25',
          'validTill': '2024-12-31',
          'dateOfBirth': '9977-01-01',
        },
      ],
      'globalInfoCty': [
        {
          'disabilityFlag': true,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

    const canonicalSchema = {
      'startDate': 'startDate',
      'endDate': 'endDate',
      'peopleId': 'peopleId',
      'personalData': {
        'names': 'names',
        'addresses': 'addresses',
        'birthInfo': 'birthInfo',
        'disabilityInfo ': {
          path: 'globalInfoCty',
          fn: (globalInfoCty) => Array.isArray(globalInfoCty) ? globalInfoCty.map((info) => info.disabilityFlag) : [],
        },
        'username': {
          path: 'emailIds',
          fn: (emailIds) => Array.isArray(emailIds) ? emailIds.map((info) => info.networkId) : [],
        },
      },
    };
    
    const schemaConversion = async (source, schema) => new Promise((resolve) => {
      const target = morphism.morphism(schema, source);
      console.log('schemaConversion finish...');
      resolve(target);
    });
    
    schemaConversion(people.splits[0], canonicalSchema)
        .then((result) => {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
        });
```

I want to take 'canonicalSchema' out from the code and save it to canonicalSchema.json, then call it like this:
import canonicalSchema from './canonicalSchema.json'; but I still want to refer to 'disabilityInfo' and ''username' in the 'canonicalSchema.json'

The problem canonicalSchema contains logic for extracting 'disabilityInfo' and 'username', which can not be saved in stand alone json file.
What suppose to be content of 'canonicalSchema.json' and how to calculate 'disabilityInfo' and 'username' in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const morphism = require('morphism');
const rawSchema = '../schema/canonicalSchema.json';
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// Read the JSON file
const rawSchemaPath = path.join(__dirname, rawSchema);
const jsonString = fs.readFileSync(rawSchemaPath, 'utf-8');

// Parse the JSON string to get the object
const canonicalSchema = JSON.parse(jsonString, function(key, value) {
  // Check if the value is a string and looks like a function
  if (key === 'fn' && typeof value === 'string') {
    // Convert the string into an actual function
    return new Function(`return ${value}`)();
  }
  return value;
});

//Rest of the code
```